# Reload tab after clicking on clickable icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need some help with two ajax function i have:

`getStatus()` - Printing a status table from API.

`disable()` - Getting a key of a record from the status table and disable it. After that, the record suppose to be removed form the status table. I'm calling this function from a clickable icon that appears for each record in the status table.

```
function getStatus() {
    var ex = document.getElementById('getStatusTable');
    if (  $.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable( ex ) ) {
         var oTable = $('#getStatusTable').dataTable()
         oTable.fnClearTable();
         oTable.fnDraw()
         oTable.fnDestroy();
    }

    $.ajax(
        {
            url : '/control/status',
            type: "GET",
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                theRows = extract_status_data(data)
                $("#getStatusTable tbody").html(theRows)

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('error')
            }
        });
    }

    function extract_status_data(jsonDataRaw){
        jsonResultSect = jsonDataRaw['result']
        retTable = ""
        retText = "ret text <br/>"
        for( key in jsonResultSect){
            anaMatStat = jsonResultSect[key]

            A = anaMatStat['A']
            B = anaMatStat['B']
            C = anaMatStat['C']
            D = anaMatStat['D']

            retTable += "<tr><td><img id='disable_"+ key+ "' value='Deactive' src='/img/deactive.png' width='20' height='20' key="+key+ " onclick=disable("+ key+") /> </td><td>" + A +  "</td><td>" +B + "</td><td>" + C + "</td><td>" + D"</td></tr>"

        }
        return retTable
    }

  function disable(key){
  $.ajax(  {
            url : '/control/disable?key='+key,
            type: "GET",
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                   
                  $("#getStatusTable").children().remove()
                 getStatus()
                 $("#getStatusTable").html(data)
                 $("#getStatusTable").show()
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('error')
            }
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <div style="margin-top:10px;width:50%">
        <ul id="af_main_tab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist"  >
            <li class="active" ><a href="#otherTab" sonclick="alert('not ready')" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" > Other Tab</a></li>
            <li > <a href="#getStatus" onclick="getStatus()" data-toggle="tab" > Status </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


   <div class="internal-frame">
        <div  id="main-content-div" style="margin:0px auto;"  >
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane" id="getStatus">
                    <table id="getStatusTable"  class="table table-condensed table-striped">
                        <div style="margin-top:10px;width:50%">
                            <thead>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>A</th>
                                <th>B</th>
                                <th>C</th> 
                                <th>D</th> 
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </div>
                    </table>
            </div>

                <div class="tab-pane active" id="otherTab">
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to refresh the status table after clicking on the clickable icon. These function are working properly on the back end side. However, the table doesn't reloaded after i click on the clickable icon. It's happen only when i reload it manually. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix it?

Comment: need to see the html to understand the issue.

Comment: so to understand the steps if testing this, you call the 'getStatus' method first then the 'disable' or what? sorry it is not clear enough for me

Comment: Yes. I'm calling to getStatus in order to get the status table, and print it. The status table show only the active keys. Each record in the status table is representing a key which can be disabled by clicking on a clickable icon which appearing for each row. After disabling the key, it's not suppose appear any in the status table. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: so the issue happen when you call the getStatus , correct?

Comment: No. The issue happen when i call `disable` function (the clickable icon is calling to this function). `getStatus` give me the list of the active keys, and `disable` is disable one of the keys. Here is the scenario: One of the tabs is presenting a status table of active keys --> I want to disable one of the keys, so i click on the clickable icon (which call to `disable`) --> Now i want to refresh the the status table (i expect to see the same table minus the key I've just disable) --> However, i see the same table. It doesn't refresh (even i get the updated status table from the API).

Comment: The goal is to refresh the status table immediately after clicking on the clickable icon.

Comment: You have a wrong HTML code, the <div class="tab-pane" id="getStatus"> has the same id as <table id="getStatus"  class="table table-condensed table-striped">. And also what it suppose to be in data parameter on success method of function disable(key)?

Comment: Add `;return false;` right after `getStatus()` on your link/icon's `onclick=`

Comment: @kizisoft: I fixed the ID issue. It happened because i had to change the code, in order to post it here. As for the disable(key) output - the success  output from the API is look like this: {  "host" : "my-pc",  "ts" : "Tue May 19 15:47:01 2015",  "status" : "Ok"}

Comment: PS - you also can replace `$('#getStatusTable')` with a cached version.  Instead of just `var ex = doc...()` you can say `var ex = doc...(), $ex = $(ex)` and replace all the instances of `$('#getStatusTable')` in the scope with `$ex`.  You can expand this by defining these outside of either function and replace both scopes' `$('#getStatusTable')` with `$ex`.  None of this will help you with your problem but you haven't responded in a bit so this is just for kicks

Comment: @Deryck: Thanks for your answer. Can you please port your answer in a different thread? (Click on "Post your answer"). It would be much easier to continue, since there are too many replies over here.

Comment: In your `disable`'s success function you call `getStatus` which changes the table's body, then you completely overwrite the table's html (back in the success function), why?

Comment: @Omri You fixed part of your question in an edit which makes my answer partially incorrect.

Comment: @m4ktub are you referring to the `onclick="disable(key1)"` issue? If so, I've tried to do it as you recommended, but for some reason i have a syntax problem or something like that. However, your solution is works great anyway, so i didn't fixed the code at the at the end...

Comment: @Omri Your last edit added the missing "+" at the end of the line. You can check the edit history to see what I'm talking about. Now my answer mentions a missing `+` that, in fact, is not missing. It's there.

Comment: @m4ktub i reverted my `+` fix it the original message. Hope is that you're referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several little issues with your Javascript code. For example, in `extract_status_data` the `retTable += ...` line is missing a `+` sign to the end of it, when adding `D`. Also, on that same line, you are adding `onclick="disable(key1)"` instead of the intended `onclick="disable('key1')"` so you need to insert some `'` in there.

Besides that, when someone clicks disable you are removing all children of the table. This includes the `tbody` and then nothing gets added again. It should, at least, be

```
$("#getStatusTable tbody").children().remove()
```

After that you are calling `getStatus`, which fills the table, and also replacing everything directly. You should also check that. The result from `getStatus` will *win*, at the end, because the response is processed asynchronously, that is, after all that code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Add `;return false;` right after `getStatus()` on your link/icon's `onclick=`

```
<a href="#getStatus" onclick="getStatus();return false;" data-toggle="tab">
```

Comment: It didn't helped. It's seems like nothing has changed. The table has not been updated (although at the back end side everything works fine , and i can see the updated status table from the API).

Comment: What do you see in the network part of devtools?  Does the browser get a response?  If it does post exactly what the data is in your question.

Comment: Done. It's seems like the problem is that the status result comes before the disable function. The disable functions suppose the come first, then i want to refresh the table by calling to the status table one more time. Dio you know how to fix it?

Comment: well given that I can't find a call to `disable()` anywhere in either of those sets of code, I'd say try replacing `getStatus();return false;` with `disable();return false;`.  Even if that's not exactly how you want the page, it'll be useful for troubleshooting.  And when I say "response" and "exactly what the data is" I mean the actual response text you'll find in the body of the message.  Also, if you have `disable()` run before `getStatus()` you won't see the result of the status because your disable removes the element that the status is trying to use as a container.

Comment: I added the call to the disable() function. Hope it will help to figure our the issue. As for the calling order problem i mentioned above - It's not relevant anymore. Can't explain why, but it's not happen anymore. The the calling order is OK, but the table is been refreshed only manually.